# Adjective for "Let It Go"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

With respect to injustices of which one is a victim,  or other unhappy events that happened to oneself, what is the adjective for "*being able to let it go and not let it eat at oneself*"?

Comment: How about *resentless, forgiving*?

Comment: You can try *stoic*.

Comment: The just descriptor would hinge upon the severity of the suffering or injustice.  Is it Boethius having ropes tightened around his skull or someone putting up with not getting a raise at work?

Answer (score 3):

*Long-suffering, forbearing, forgiving, tolerant, patient, accommodating, uncomplaining, untroubled* and *imperturbable* are a few. If you look those words up in the dictionary, you will find slight differences in the meaning of most of them. You can also put them into a thesaurus and find yet more words.

Answer (score 1):

A modern colloquial adjective is **zen**.

> They gave the promotion to his junior colleague, a young woman who had been at the company for less than a year, but he was very **zen** about it.